# как можно убрать возможность скачивания видео внутри тега iframe

Tags: html, iframe

```
      <iframe
        v-if="lesson.type_of === 'video'"
        width="100%" 
        :src="lesson.video_ru">
      </iframe>
```

у меня видео воспроизводится внутри тега iframe. У самого видео есть возможность скачивания, как можно убрать его?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756837/prevent-html5-video-from-being-downloaded-right-click-saved